# Infinite axline in 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to draw a scene like in the picture below using Python matplotlib, but I got stuck on drawing the infinite line (the black & dotted one in the picture). In 2D, this line can be drawn using `axline`, but I couldn't find an alternative in 3D.

Is there any solution to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ax.hline` and `ax.vline` are parallel to the respective axis.
as a workaround, you can use

```
ax.plot((x_0, x_1), (y_0, y_1), (z_0, z_1), color='k', linestyle='dashed')
```

with sufficiently far away points and appropriately scaled xyz-lims.

Comment: All ax.hline, ax.vline, and ax.axline are for 2D and there is no correspondence in 3D.